# Overlaying text on an image in an email from javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html-email

I have a form that submits email contact information and a message.  I am trying to format the email in javascript and submit for sending. The message is inserted into the html in javascript and then sent as the body of the email.
The html is a table - one tr is set up with the image in it and I am trying to overlay the message in a specific place (the box).  My code is below.  The result is that the message prints in the email and then the image appears - no overlaying at all.
The entire HTML is a string assembled in the javascript and passed as the email body.  All styling (css) is done in-line.

The code for the  is shown, along with the results obtained.

html:

[image: code for the table row where the message is expected to overlay the image]

Results: the text is desired to go in the white box.

[image: text prints above the image, not over it.]

Comment: Please add your code in editable format. Use the markdown for syntax highlighting, you will find some help here : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Code added as link to a png. Markdown should be used instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910512/email-background-image)